# How do we connect Apache web server to weblogic server by using weblogic plugin for Apache?

Tags: apache, plugins, webserver, weblogic, integration

Could you please guide me in this question. I couldn't find the installation or setup stuff for this. If you found any thing related  please post it here. I appreciate your help. I did a lot of research but I couldn't understand the way it explains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick google search brings back the Oracle Documentation for the [Weblogic Apache Plugin](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/plugins/apache.html).